# Is there a reason why the akka local tcp port is set to 0?

Tags: scala, akka

From [Alvin's remote actor example](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-akka-actors-remote-example):

```
akka {
  loglevel = "INFO"

  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }

    log-sent-messages = on
    log-received-messages = on
  }

}
```

Is there a reason why the local tcp port is set to 0?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he set the port to 0 on the "local" project because he doesn't care what the port is. He's only ever going to be sending messages *from* that project. He specifically set the port of the "remote" project because he needed to know it so that he could send a message to an actor there.